# Proof question: Sequences of measurable functions $f_n$, such that for almost all $x$, set $f_n(x)$ is bounded...

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

##### Problem statement

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions in a finite measure space $X$. Suppose that for almost every $x$, $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a bounded set. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a positive number $c$ and a measurable set $E$ with $\mu(X-E) < \epsilon$, such that $|f_n(x)| \leq c$ for all $x \in E, n = 1, 2, \ldots$.

##### Attempt at proof

First, define $g(x) := \sup_n |f_n(x)|$. From Theorem A ($f$ measurable $\implies |f|$ measurable) and Theorem B ($f_n$ measurable for all $n$ $\implies$ $\sup_n f_n$ measurable), it follows that $g$ is measurable. Thus, $\{ x : g(x) \leq c \}$ is measurable for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, let $E := \{ x : g(x) \leq c \}$ for some $c$ such that $\mu(X \setminus E) < \epsilon$. **(???)**. Thus $|f_n(x)| \leq c$ for all $x \in E, n = 1, 2, \ldots$.

##### Questions

Is this a proof of the statement? In particular, at the part marked with **(???)**, I am wondering if the existence of $c$ needs elaboration, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Note that the assumption on the $x \in \mathrm{X}$ ensures $g < \infty$ almost everywhere. But then, $\{g < \infty\} = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbf{Z}_+} \{n - 1 < g <= n\}$ is a union of disjoint sets, so the measure of the set in the left is the series of the measures of the sets of the right, which implies the tail of such series is negligible, but the tail correspond to the $\{g > K\}$ (for some $K \in \mathbf{N}$). Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g:=\sup_{n}|f_{n}(x)|$, which is measurable (but possibly takes
value $\infty$). Let $A=\{x\in X\mid\{f_{n}(x)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}\mbox{ is bounded\}}.$
By assumption, $\mu(X\setminus A)=0$.  Let $B=\{x\in X\mid g(x)\in\mathbb{R}\}$
and $B_{n}=\{x\in X\mid g(x)\leq n\}$. Clearly $B_{1}\subseteq B_{2}\subseteq\ldots$
and $B=\cup_{n}B_{n}$. By continuity of measure, $\mu(B)=\lim_{n}\mu(B_{n})$.
Note that $A=B$ and $\mu(X)<\infty$, so we have that $0=\mu(A^{c})=\mu(B^{c})=\mu(X)-\mu(B)=\mu(X)-\lim_{n}(B_{n})$.
Given $\varepsilon>0$, we can choose $n$ such that $\mu(X)-\mu(B_{n})<\varepsilon$.
Put $c=n$ and $E=B_{n}$. Now, for each $x\in E$, we have that $g(x)\leq n\Rightarrow|f_{k}(x)|\leq c$
for all $k$. Moreover, $\mu(X\setminus E)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: I guess you mean "we can choose $n$ such that $\mu(X) - \mu(B_n) < \epsilon$", otherwise: thanks!

Comment: Yes. It is a typo. Let me fix it.